# global cluster object for dispy

Tags: dispy

(1) Can I have the cluster object global across machines so that once a job is submitted, that job in turn can submit other dissimilar smaller jobs?

```
cluster = dispy.JobCluster(compute)
```

(2) Can the "compute" function be different each time I invoke a submit?

Answer (score 0):

(1) I believe you need to look into the `SharedCluster` object, of which I'm not familiar.

(2) You can create different "functions" inside of the `compute` function using `if` statements and passing a selection argument to `compute`:

```
def compute(param):

    if param == 'a':
        'Do something'
    if param == 'b':
        'Do something else'

cluster = dispy.JobCluster(compute)

for i in params:

    cluster.submit(i)
```